# how to fetch id and name using typeahead plugin

Tags: jquery, json, typeahead

i want to to display name as well as their id in typeahead plugin something like this

### name1 (id1),
 name2 (id2),
 name3 (id3)

am using the following code to initialize the typeahead plugin

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
var users=new Bloodhound({

    datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
    queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: 'users.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
      }﻿

});
﻿ 
users.initialize();

$("#users").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minlength: 2



},{
    name: 'users',
    displayKey:'username',      
    source:users.ttAdapter()


});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

1.first thing  change your suggestion into a link

```
{
    name: 'users',
    display:'SearchName',       
    source:users.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (users) {
        return '<p><a href="index.php?userid='+users.CustomerId+'" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;width:100%"><span class="crop"><img src="images/img2.jpg" widht="50px" height="50px"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+users.SearchName+'<br /><span style="text-decoration:none;":false;">'+users.FullAddress+'</span></a></p>';
        }
}
```

by doing this you can create a link with a image jus like how it's in facebook